# Creating a LUT in Photoshop with a Vignette

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing

I’m trying to create an LUT in Photoshop that includes a vignette that makes the centre of the image brighter. I would usually achieve this effect by creating a new fill layer (new gradient fill), changing the style to radial, selecting reverse and change the blending mode to soft light at 45%. However, you can’t use a fill layer for a LUT - only an adjustment layer.

Is there anyway this effect can be achieved through an adjustment layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adda a vignette to a LUT or curves layer by vignetting the mask…

Picture
[image]

Aggressive curve
[image]

Vignette on curves layer mask
[image]
[image]

Result
[image]

Again with a LUT (I don't really do LUTs so it took me a while to figure where they were ;)

[image]

And with added (overkill) brightness done on a separate adjustment layer. Opt(alt)/drag the mask, opt/click it & Invert.
[image]